# NumberFormatException with calculator

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I'm making a calculator, and I'm getting a `NumberFormatException`.

This is the code for my method:

```
String[] parts = text.getText().split(" + ", 2);
temporary[0] = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
temporary[1] = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
answer = temporary[0] + temporary[1];
```

This is the code for my class:

```
public int answer = 0;
public int[] temporary = {0, 0};
```

I'm getting the NFE on this line:

```
temporary[0] = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
```

Any ideas why?

This is my stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8 + 9"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at main.Calculator.actionPerformed(Calculator.java:123)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What does `getText()` return?

Comment: Why are you parsing `parts[0]` twice? Also have you tried printing its value?

Comment: Why are you multiplying when the operand is addition?

Comment: Could you please paste your stack trace?

Comment: Try `temporary[0] = Integer.parseInt(parts[0].trim());`. This removes whitespace.

Comment: This fellow is clearly early in his programming career. I don't think he is being treated well on Stack Overflow. Of the 4 Close votes, 1 is Off Topic and 3 are Too Broad. The senior folks casting those votes could demonstrate their superior skills by reading the provided stack trace. In this case, they could help `user3234092` further his programming skills by explaining the stack trace and  how the `regex` bit him. [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` uses regex so `split(" + ")` will try to split on two or more continues spaces and since your String probably don't have such spaces it will not be split so `parts[0]` will hold entire original String. Because of that your code will try to parse something like

```
Integer.parseInt("123 + 321")`
```

which throws `NumberFormatException` because it is not correct integer this method can parse. Try escaping `+` in split. You can also make spaces optional.

Try with

```
String[] parts = text.getText().split("\\s*\\+\\s*", 2);
```

---

Also note that you are trying to parse `parts[0]` twice. Change your

```
temporary[1] = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
```

to

```
temporary[1] = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Comment: The stack trace `NumberFormatException: For input string: "8 + 9"` that he just posted confirms that this is the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `split` is a regular expression.  If you're looking for a plus sign, this string won't do the job, because `" + "` means look for 1 or more spaces, followed by another space.  That is, it looks for 2 or more spaces as a delimiter.  So if your input string is `"2 + 2"`, there's no 2-space sequence, so `split` will return a one-element array with `"2 + 2"` as the string.  This isn't the right format for a number.

To search for a space followed by a plus sign followed by a space:

```
String[] parts = text.getText().split(" \\+ ", 2);
```

Then fix it so it doesn't multiply when they ask to add two numbers  :)  [OK, you did that.]

**Note:** If you eventually want to let your users do something besides addition, you probably won't be able to use `split` without a fairly complex regular expression.  That's because `split` won't return the delimiters.  That's fine if the only possible delimiter is `+`, but if you can have other operators, you'll need to know what the operator is, so `split` won't work.  You'll need to use more general regex matching.  See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says why.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

> Throws:
>
> NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Comment: From the stack trace, he is trying to parse `8 + 9` and split on ` + `.

Answer (score 0):

As many has pointed out here, you must check first if the string you want to parse actually contains a number or not.

Now, if your idea is to parse an expression for evaluation, the right paths for such a task are

- use an evaluator like beanshell (the easier way IMO - http://www.beanshell.org/manual/embeddedmode.html) or
- write your own grammar (or reuse an existent one) to do the parse (I am specially fond of ANTLR4 - https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Home)

Comment: From the stack trace, he is trying to parse `8 + 9` and split on ` + `.

Comment: and then he´s trying to write the answer, so he´s trying to evaluate the expression